# Show chapter in Table of Contents but do not print its header in text

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters

I would like to list some pages of my report under a chapter. This chapter should be printed in the text without the header but with an entry in the Table of Contents.

It should look like this:

```
TOC:
 1. chapter1
 2. chapter2
 3. chapter3

chapter1:
 LOREM IPSUM
chapter2:
 LOREM IPSUM

% from here on I would like to list the text under chapter 3 in the ToC 
% but don't what to print "Chapter 3:" at all
 LOREM IPSUM
```

This would be something like `\addcontentsline{file}{sec_unit}{entry}` but without printing the chapter header in text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

+1 You got it, `\addcontentsline` really exists!

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{My Dummy Chapter Title}
```

Issuing `\cleardoublepage` is necessary only if you want your non-chapter to start on a new page. Issuing `\phantomsection` is necessary only when you load the `hyperref` package.